How can I get more space between the contents of a bNiceArray and the enclosing brackets?
How can I get more space between the contents of a bNiceArray and the enclosing brackets?
I want to highlight rows without visual issues from things overlapping.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,hf-tikz}
\begin{document}
I want to highlight a row in a bNiceArray from the package nicematrix using hf-tikz.
This works with regular arrays with manually placed delimeters, but in nicematrix, the brackets are too close.
\[
\text{text}\begin{bNiceArray}[baseline=1]{ccc}
    \tikzmarkin[disable rounded corners=true,thin]{a}(.5ex,-.5ex)(-.5ex,2ex)1&2&3\tikzmarkend{a}\\
    a&b&c
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
Notice how the same highlighting fits just fine in an array with manual delimeters:
\[
\text{text}
\left[
\begin{array}[t]{ccc}
    \tikzmarkin[disable rounded corners=true,thin]{b}(.5ex,-.5ex)(-.5ex,2ex)1&2&3\tikzmarkend{b}\\
    a&b&c
\end{array}
\right]
\]
\end{document}



Without hf-tikz.  As I have never done this, I tested with the example from the documentation p.70
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}



\tikzset{highlight/.style={
    rectangle,
    fill=orange!15,
    draw=purple,
    % rounded corners = 0.5 mm,
    inner sep=1pt,
    fit=#1
    }
}
\[
\text{text}
\begin{bNiceArray}[
    baseline=2,
    margin,
    % extra-margin=1.ex,
    ]{ccc}
    \CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
    \tikz \node [highlight = (2-1) (2-3)] {} ;
    % \tikz \draw [fill=orange!15,draw=purple] (1-|1) |- (2-|4) |- cycle;
\Body
    \\
    1&2&3\\
    a&b&c
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}



Thank you, the use of margin solves the problem.
